# rails validate data and get data using strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, strong-parameters

I have 3 tables

```
User(id,email)
Org(id,name)
Role(id,user_id,org_id,role)
```

Ajax request send parameters

```
org[name]   test
org[user][email]    test@test.com
```

In my controller

```
def create 
  client_org = Org.new(client_org_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  @client_org.valid?
  if !@client_org.errors.blank?
    format.json { render json: @client_org.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    elsif Org.saveClientOrg(@client_org)

  end
end
private
def client_org_params
  params.require(:client_org).permit(:name,user_attributes: [:email])
end
```

In Org.model

```
def self.saveClientOrg(orgData)
    org=ClientOrg.new(orgData.name)//-->okay I got name: test
    orgData.user.email //error? undefined method `user' for #<Org>
end
```

Seem like this line code: orgData.user.email incorrect.

when I leave 2 input field blank and submit form ==> form validate says only name is blank and ignore email.Although in model user.rb I set validates :email, presence: true
Anyone help me? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
User.rb
has_many :roles
has_many :orgs, through: :roles
default_scope -> { order('email ASC') }
validates_format_of :email, :with  => Devise.email_regexp
validates :email, presence: true

Org.rb
has_many :roles
has_many :users, through: :roles
validates :name, presence: true , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

Role.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :org
```

Comment: Pls specify Associations of each Model and view calling `create` action of controller.

Comment: i think that you can find some good hints about how to debug your problem in this article: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

`orgData` is your `org` model's active record object right?

so in org.rb you need to do this

> orgData.users.email

user should be plural `users`

Comment: your code: orgData.users.email raise error-->undefined method `email' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: try this : `orgData.users.first.email`

Comment: Parameters POST ajax: {"utf8"=>"✓", "org"=>{"name"=>"test", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com"}}, "done"=>"Done"}--> unable get email

Comment: if this is your parameter structure then you can access the `email` parameter as `params["org"]["user"]["email"]` that will get you the value of `email` key